# Safe way to refresh iptables without traffic leak

Tags: iptables

I have an iptables file that looks like this more or less:

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $(dig +short somedomain.com) -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $(dig +short somedomain.com) -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

I have a cron set to run this every hour. What worries me is the probability between iptables -F and the end of the script to have some packets leak. Is there another way that I can run this without having to run iptables -F at the beggining?

Comment: Don't run it every hour, of course.

Comment: There is a dynamically updated rule in the set of rules (the dig command) that needs to be updated.

Comment: So, do that separately in a different chain, not in INPUT.

Comment: Or use an [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/), that you update, and reference in your rules.

Comment: Since `dig` can take time and because it is useless and even dangerous to do it twice (it may give you two different responses!), you should do it before your iptables rules, and store result in some variable to be used by your iptables rules. That would also enable you to check the reply and that is makes sense before using it blindly elsewhere. Also I would recommend both stating resource record type and specifically which nameserver you query. You could also do a DROP right after flush (or setting default to DROP), and remove it only at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on the suggestion to use ipset, which looks to me like the best solution, lets first prepare the set:

```
ipset create netset hash:net
ipset add netset 192.168.56.0/24
ipset add netset 10.0.0.0/8
ipset add netset 127.0.0.1
ipset add netset somedomain.com
```

You can verify what's the resultant set with

```
ipset save netset
```

Now the tables:

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set netset src -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m set --match-set netset dst -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Now the update:

```
ipset create newnetset hash:net
ipset add newnetset 192.168.56.0/24
ipset add newnetset 10.0.0.0/8
ipset add newnetset 127.0.0.1
ipset add newnetset somedomain.com
ipset swap newnetset netset
ipset destroy newnetset
```

Please note that relying on DNS in firewall rules is usually considered not the safest thing to do. I guess you are trying to allow communication with the host which is on residental internet connection and you are trying to rely on some kind of dynamic DNS to keep the rules up to date with changing IP address. Using VPN on event some kind of port knocking may be better solution.

Answer (score 2):

> What worries me is the probability between iptables -F and the end of the script to have some packets leak.

Well right now you are DROP all packets via a rule.  If you set the **policy** of your INPUT/OUTPUT chains to DROP, that **policy would not be reset by a flush**.

```
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Though using a ipset, or a chain for your dynamic rules instead of flushing the entire table would probably be a better solution.